# General-linear polynomial model with python (for Output-Error model)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, statsmodels

I need to create a **general-linear polynomial model** with python. And as definitions for this type of models vary I'd note that I refer to [this reference by *NI*](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/372458C-01/lvsysidconcepts/modeldefinitionsgl/). I guess that *Matlab*'s implementation is quite similar.

[image]

I am particularly interested in creating an **Output-Error model** (OE) with it's initialization handled by **Prediction Error Method** (PEM).

[image]

I've been looking through **scikit**, **statsmodels** and some time-series and stat libraries on github but failed to meet the suite that addresses this very task.

I would be grateful for both:

- suggestions of ready-made modules/libs
- (if none exists) advice on creating my own lib: perhaps, building on top of Numpy, Scipy or one of the mentioned above.

Thank you.

P.S.: A module just for OE/PEM would be sufficient but I doubt this exists separately from other linear polynomial model libs.

Comment: this goes under the name of *System Identification* and as far as I know statsmodels and scikit doesn't deal with this and they are not related. There is an absence of a SysID package in Python and other languages not only because there are limited users but because these methods are not that successful and have very little demand. You can solve manually if you need to have to solve this particular instance.